# Why is my R plot using ts_plot including a line between the first and last points?

Tags: r, plot, line

I am using the R package `rtweet` to stream and plot the tweets about the Super Bowl event on Sunday. I have parsed the data, and am trying to plot it, but there is a white line between two data points that keeps coming up and I can't work out why.

It would be great to get rid of this white line, as it is quite distracting. I am a bit of a rookie so any help would be appreciated! Below is the code I was using to plot the parsed data (`superbowl`).

[Here's an image of the output that I have got.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AYNb.jpg)

```
    superbowl %>% 
         ts_filter(by="7.5 mins",
                   filter=c("patriots|pats|patriotsnation","falcons|dirty birds|riseup"),
                   key=c("Patriots","Falcons"),
                   trim=TRUE) %>%
         ts_plot(theme="spacegray",
                 cols=c("#0D254C","#A6192D"),
                 main="Tweets during Super Bowl LI",
                 subtitle="Tweets collected and parsed using 'rtweet'",
                 cex.legend=1.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure how to solve the problem but an alternative might be to use the base function:

`plot(dataset[,1],type='l')`

where 1 is the number of the column your plotting and l gives the traditional time series line between observations.